# LLDB command history search by starting characters similar to GDB readline?

Tags: debugging, gdb, readline, lldb, editline

Is there a way to search LLDB commands similar to the readline library's [history-search-backward](https://www.reddit.com/r/linux/comments/1gfwls/didnt_know_bash_has_incremental_history_searching/) in bash and GDB?

I want to be able to type some characters, and use up arrow to cycle through all commands that start with those characters.

Answer (score 2):

lldb uses editline rather than readline.  Editline has a backward search in command history feature (em-inc-search-prev) that's bound to `^R` by default (though you can change this in your .editrc)  It works like emac's `^S`, you type characters to refine the search, and `^R` to go to the previous match.  To reverse direction and start searching forward you would use em-inc-search-next, but we haven't bound that to anything.

Comment: One feature of readline that does not seem to be present in editline is the ability to only cycle through commands that start with a certain letter. Here's what I like to do: set breakpoints with `b <addr>`, and in gdb, type `b`, then up-arrow to cycle through previous breakpoints. If i do `b`, then ctrl-r, I have to cycle through all commands that contain a `b` in them, not just commands that start with `b`.

Is there any way to do this?